# PostgreSQL variable null or in null syntax error

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I use `psycopg2` and have input varaiables with a where condition that looks like this:

```
WHERE %(variable)s is null or some_column in %(variable)s
```

The problem is that when `variable` is null I get a syntax error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "NULL"`
(NULL is null or (some_column IN NULL)) and
                                 ^
```

That condition should of course not be evaluated since `null is null` is true already, but the syntax does not pass. Anyway to fix this without creating an extra variable?

Comment: Syntax error is about brackets. Correct syntax is `some_column in (NULL) ` not `some_column IN NULL`

Comment: @Kadet It's a variable and will be a tuple sometimes and null other times. I need it to work even when it is null. That's why I have the first condition.

Comment: add brackets, and put in brackets one value or many values, thats all. Or build this condition dinamicaly omitting this part in case it's not needed. There can be `some_column in (NULL) ` or `some_column in (NULL,2)` but not `some_column in NULL`

Comment: @Kadet I tried `COALESCE(%(variable)s, (NULL))` but get `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "COALESCE"` then too.

Comment: Try ANY https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/psycopg2/2.7.5/usage.html